# Transit visa requirement. EgyptAir Mumbai to Toronto via Cairo

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, cai

We are Indian passport holders, with valid visas for Canada. Plan is to take the EgyptAir flight Mumbai to Toronto, via Cairo. Problem is Egypt embassy website says we don't need Transit Visa if transit is up to 12 hours but here transit is 14 hours.

Has anyone with a Indian passport traveled this route?
What was your experience at Cairo?
Did you need a transit visa?

Comment: Government in Egypt supports EgyptAir a lot, so I would not be surprised if they let you do the transfer on EgyptAir without a visa, just call an EgyptAir office and check.

Answer (score 1):

When you check in at the airport, which may be staffed by contractors not fully versed in EgyptAir policies, the check in agent will see the following information:

```
Information as of  11MAY15 / 1315 UTC
National India (IN)             /Embarkation India (IN)
Transit Egypt (EG)              /Destination Canada (CA)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
Egypt (EG)  

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
time of 12 hours.
- Leaving the airport is permitted for passengers with transit
time between 6 and 12 hours. Passengers with transit time of
less than 6 hours may leave the transit area but not the
airport.
```

Therefore, I advise you obtain something in writing from EgyptAir confirming that your will be permitted on board the aircraft; failing that I would advise you to obtain the appropriate visa.

The check in agent will not violate what is said by TIMATIC unless they have a very good reason to do so, which could require a phone call from EgyptAir in Cairo.